# Magento 2: How to Add another block in sales/invoice page.

Tags: magento2, invoice, sales, page

i want to add another block in invoice page like (Another information tab), is there a way that i can display another block or override it.

here is a snapshot in which i want to add another block

[image]

Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First,you need to create  custom module:

### Via custom module

*If you **donot want to work** at direct **vendor** folder then you need create a custom module*

This module should consist of below files:

- `app/code/app/code/{vendorname}/{Company}/registration.php`
- `app/code/{vendorname}/{Company}/composer.json`
- `app/code/{vendorname}/{Company}/etc/module.xml`

**then Create a layout file `sales_order_invoice_view.xml` at `app/code/{vendorname}/{Company}/view/adminhtml/layout`**

On this`sales_order_invoice_view.xml`  add below code for **change the template via layout for [`order_info`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_invoice_view.xml#L16)** and Also add a child  block of this block which you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" 
        label="Email Order Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
        <body>
         <referenceBlock name="order_info">
             <arguments>
             <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">{vendorname}_{Company}::sales/invoice/info.phtml</argument>
             </arguments>
             <!-- add Block -->
             <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info" name="custom.blockforinvoice" as="custom.blockforinvoice" template="vendorname}_{Company}::sales/invoice/info.phtml" />
         </referenceBlock>

    </page>
```

*Now new template phtml is located at `app/code/{vendorname}/{Company}/view/adminhtml/templates/sales/invoice/info.phtml`*.

And then copy the code of 
`vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml`

and paste on new `info.phtml` .

After, you need to call your custom block in new info.phtml  by add this code

`<?php  $block->getChildHtml('custom.blockforinvoice') ?>` after [`<?php endif; ?>`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml#L183) of shipping information

After this your should do below

*delete all file from `var/cache` and `var/view_preprocessed`  and page_cache using `rm -rf`var/cache`and`rm -rf var/view_preprocessed`,`rm -rf var/page_cache`*

Comment: Hi, Sir thanks for help but should i have to override the block file or not

Comment: A </body> tag is missing in the answer xml @amit

Comment: You have given a block on the top of the invoice not in the payment section as the person asked.